# Prism for Xamarin.Forms unable to AutoWire

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying out Prism.Forms for my next client project. Unfortunately, I am seeing a strange behavior with my samples.

**Pretext**
It seems like XF or Prism does not like me including an existing XAML page (also mentioned by Brian Lagunas - The man - himself at the Evolve session). But renaming a page also throws it off and the ViewModelLocator can't seem to locate the ViewModel anymore. Even if I re-create the page with same name, It can't find it ViewModel. Manually setting the BindingContext works, but I am trying not to create my dependencies for constructor injection.

**Question**
While working on existing code, a minor change caused NullReference exception when using NavigationPage as a root. Here is an example of a working sample app

https://github.com/hnabbasi/xamarin/tree/master/XFPrism/XFPrism

I am using a NavigationPage and pushing a ContentPage. Then I push another ContentPage, then I show a Modal page via button click and communicate. I send parameters back to Second content page via NavigationParameters.

To break it, simply try to swap the ISayHello service with IPageDialogService. I am not sure what's going on that's breaking it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ok. Found the issue with renaming. I found that when the Views were not directly under "Views" namespace (i.e. Views.Pages, or Views.Dashboard), they did not load. Moving them directly under "Views" worked without an error.

Also, I had to remove the explicit AutowireViewModel = "True" declaration in XAML as it is taken care of by the ViewModelLocator already. Then, the ViewModelLocator was able to locate and bind my views just fine.

Still not sure about the NullReference when calling a injected Service's method from the Constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Dan S. in the comments. The MainPage is not set when I was calling the PageDialogService to display the alert, hence the NullReference.

In case you really need to do something like this where you want to somehow wait for something to finish before doing an operation, try `Task.Yield()`.

I fixed my scenario as below,

```
    // will yield for current operation of page appearing
    await Task.Yield(); 

    // by now, the page has appeared and set, so this should work fine
    SayHiCommand.Execute(this);
```

I have used this workaround in the past. If you know a better way of handing this, please comment away.

Answer (score 0):

The INavigationService is a named type and as I recall a known limitation of Unity is that named types must precede unnamed types.

Comment: I tried rearranging the dependencies in the constructor, but it didn't help. What I am confused about in the example I posted is that my ISayHello service works fine when called from the constructor, so does INavigationService, but IPageDialogService does not.

Comment: The error you are getting appears to be due to the fact that you are doing this from your MainPage. If you try to execute the page dialog service from either the constructor or OnNavigatedTo the Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage is still null. Because of this the Page Dialog Service is unable to call Xamarin Forms Display Alert method. Once the page is displayed and you click on the 'Say Hi' button it is able to execute since the MainPage has actually been set.

Comment: You are right. The MainPage is null when PageDialogService is trying to use it. Thank you :)